# Multiple AWT-Shutdown and AWT-EventQueue threads created and destroyed in Java program

Tags: java, multithreading, awt, javafx

I'm monitoring a JavaFX program in VisualVM and in the Threads view, there's a constant barrage of AWT-EventQueue-0 and AWT-Shutdown threads that are created and destroyed. Is this normal behaviour? What is the cause of this?

[image: List of threads]

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to know the exact cause without seeing all of your code, however I've seen this happen if you schedule Swing timers without a Swing/AWT GUI.

The EDT and Shutdown threads get destroyed and re-created every time the timer fires if there is not a Swing/AWT GUI present.

You have tagged this question with JavaFX if you have an JavaFX GUI you should not use the Swing `Timer` class or other Swing threading utilities such as `invokeLater()`, `invokeAndWait()` or `SwingWorker`.

Take a look inside the package `javafx.concurrent` which has support for scheduling and background tasks for the JavaFX event dispatch thread.